# How to keep scrolling div to the bottom if the user did not scroll

Tags: javascript, html, css, ejs

I want to know how can I keep a div automatically scroll down when data is updated but not if the user scrolls up, here is a function that I had written in javascript

```
function checkForScroll() {
    var element = document.getElementById("messageArea");
    if (element.scrollHeight - element.scrollTop === element.clientHeight) {
        element.scrollTop = element.scrollHeight;
    }
}

setInterval(function () {
    $("#messageArea").load(" #messageArea > *");
    setTimeout(checkForScroll(), 500)
}, 3000);
```

here is the div, it is written in ejs

```
<div class="messagesArea" id="messageArea">
        <% if (messages != "undefined") {messages.forEach(function(message) { %>
        <div class="message">
            <hr>
            <p style="font-size: 1.6vh; color: #9d9d9d;"><%- message.sender %></p>
            <p style="float: 2vh; color: white; margin-top: -1vh; width: 68vw;"><%- message.messageBody %></p>
        </div>
        <% });} %>
    </div>
```

the issue is that when the data is updated in the div with id messagesArea it does not scroll to the bottom, is there something I am doing wrong?